# How to typecast a pointer so as to adapt variable structure?

Tags: c

I am writing a function that I want to initiate a list that points to some data structure which can be changed during calling the initial function. And call the data with that. But I don't know how to make the pointer variable. I've tried to use a void pointer but don't know how to call it with structure length so there will be an error that the pointer point to empty space(I allocate the space). I've been searched some article but not helpful and I just learn C in 3 months.

Here is my code, I posted part of it. There is an initial function and empty function. I don't know how to pass the pointer size so the empty function can free the data pointer space. Hope you guys can help, thanks a lot.

```
typedef struct node{
    void *data;
    struct node *next,*prev,*head,*tail;
}Node;

typedef Node *List;

void empty_list(List plist){
    Node *tmp,*phead;
    phead=direct_to_head(plist);
    while (phead->next!=NULL) {
        tmp=phead->next;
        if(tmp->data!=NULL){
            free(tmp->data);
            tmp->data=NULL;
        }
        free(phead);
        phead=tmp;
    }
    free(phead);
    phead=NULL;
    plist=NULL;
}

List init_list(unsigned int count,size_t size){

    if(count==0)
        fprintf(stderr,"node number can't be zero");
    Node *head,*tail;
    head=(Node *)calloc(count+2, sizeof(Node));
    if(head==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "No space in initing.");
        return NULL;
    }
    tail=head+count+1;
    head->tail=head+count+1;
    head->next=head+1;
    tail->head=head;
    tail->prev=tail-1;
    while (count>0) {
        head++;
        head->data=(void *)calloc(1, size);
        if(head->data==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "No space in initing.");
            return NULL;
        }
        head->head=head-count;
        head->tail=tail;
        head->next=head+1;
        head->prev=head-1;
        count--;

    }
    return (head->head)+1;
}
```

Comment: Hiding pointers in `typedef`'s is not a good idea. The same is valid for casting results of `malloc` and friends.

Comment: Do you get an error? Where exactly in your code is the problem you cannot solve? A call to `free` doesn't need the size of the allocated memory. Your list implementation looks a bit strange because you allocating an array of `count+2` list nodes at once and use pointer arithmetics. The normal way would be to allocate nodes one by one allowing to extend or shrink the list.

Comment: I got an error when use free. pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: @Gerhardh, I just new to C. Would you mind to tell what is the best way?

Comment: You want to double check the part inside the `while`-loop. Assume  you pass 1 for `count`. Does code touch invalid memory.

Comment: Thank you. I know where go wrong....I enter the next node before empting it, so it will get into the tail node. That's what cause the error

Comment: I referred to the loop in `init_list()`!

Comment: Actually it won't. If I pass 1, then init will initiate 3*Node memory which is head-node-tail. But when I empty it, the while loop will enter the tail which cause the error because the tail has no data. I met another problem because of the allocation....I should not allocate bulk of memory, because when free the head, it will free all of the pre-allocated memory that includes nodes.....I am rookie of C, not think of that. I need to adapt my init function that to allocate node one by one which I don't think it's efficient.

Comment: Do you have another idea that I can allocate a bulk of memory and free it node by node?

Comment: "*allocate a bulk of memory and free it node by node*": No, this is not possible. The rule to follow is: do exactly *one* freeing per *one* allocation/reallocation.

Comment: @alk, thank you. Then I have to allocate the node one by one.

Answer (score 1):

> *I don't know how to pass the pointer size so the empty function can free the data pointer space.*

`free()` does not take the size, but just the pointer. So there is no need to pass the size of memory `data` points to `empty_list`.

---

To access the memory `data` points to you want to cast the pointer to the appropriate type and then dereference it.

If you for example did

```
Node * head = init_list(1, sizeof (int));
```

You could access the head's data by doing

```
*((int*) head->data) = 42;
```

Comment: Hi, I know that free() doesn't take the size. But the pointer I used in init_list function is void which can't be empty by free(). There is an error(pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug).

Comment: And I want to adapt struct size in function, that means I need to pass undefined or defined when it used structure into the functions. For example, I might use structure when I initiate the list in the first time, and use structure 2 in the next compile. I just want to simply make my functions can initiate both and free both. But structure 1 and 2 have different size so the pointer can be cover to different sizeof address.

Comment: @T.R: "*There is an error(pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug).*" you might like to *add* the code to your question which exactly provokes this error.

Comment: That is in empty function  @alk. When I use free(). I think that is because the pointer is not typecast when it use void. I want to know if there any good ways to empty the space.

Comment: Thank you. I know where go wrong....I enter the next node before empting it, so it will get into the tail node. That's what cause the error